# XML and XSD - Sub-Elements only valid when certain Parent Attribute is selected?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, attributes

Is it possible to declare in the XSD that a sub-element is only valid when the parent element has a specific attribute selected?

So for example in the xml:

```
<dropdown style="radiobuttons">
<button>my first choice</button>
<button>my second choice</button>
<button>my third choice</button>
</dropdown>

<dropdown style="checkboxes">
<checkbox>my first choice</checkbox>
<checkbox>my second choice</checkbox>
<checkbox>my third choice</checkbox>
</dropdown>
```

but the below would be invalid / the schema would not support it as the button element is to be only used with style="radiobutton"

```
<dropdown style="checkboxes">
<button>my first choice</button>
<button>my second choice</button>
<checkbox>my third choice</checkbox>
</dropdown>
```

I'm aware that the choices would need to be controlled in the xsd by xs:enumeration

Answer (score 0):

XSD 1.0 does not support that sort of conditional type assignment, but XSD 1.1 does:

### XSD 1.1 Solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="dropdown">
    <xs:alternative test="@style eq 'radiobuttons'" type="RadioButtonsType" />
    <xs:alternative test="@style eq 'checkboxes'" type="CheckBoxesType" />
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="RadioButtonsType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="button" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CheckBoxesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="checkbox" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

However, note that you can avoid the need for XSD 1.1 and conditional type assignment here very naturally simply by using different container elements for `button` elements and `checkbox` elements rather than using `dropdown` for both.